# How can I use indeces to remove specific values from a dataframe?

Tags: r, subset

I have used the `which()` function to generate indices that tell me which values in variable `x` of a 9-variable dataframe are above 1024 and to tell me which values in variable `y` are above 768.

Now I want to generate a new dataframe that includes all the values of the original dataframe except for all values returned by `which (dataframe$x > 1024)` or `which (dataframe$y > 768`

What functions can I use to generate a new dataframe from the old dataframe minus those indexed values?

I apologize if my language is not standardized to typical R vocabulary, I just started working with R. Thanks.

Comment: You can use logical vectors for subsetting. Try `dataframe[dataframe$x <= 1024 & dataframe$y <= 768,]` which is the same as `dataframe[!(dataframe$x > 1024 | dataframe$y > 768),]`.

Comment: Thanks Roland, that worked. Could you please tell me how to get more information regarding the use of logical vectors for subsetting? What help() command should I use to understand this better?

Comment: Please read http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf.

Comment: I've transformed my comments into an answer. You can now tick the green check-mark.

Comment: More documents about subsetting: `?Extract`, [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) and [here](http://stat405.had.co.nz/lectures/04-subsetting.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical vectors for subsetting. Try `dataframe[dataframe$x <= 1024 & dataframe$y <= 768,]` which is the same as `dataframe[!(dataframe$x > 1024 | dataframe$y > 768),]`.

You would benefit from reading an [introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If logical vectors are not intuitive for you, you may prefer using `subset()`. 
In your case:

`subset(dataframe, (x > 1024 | y > 768))`

However you should pay attention to NA's and (c&p from the manual of subset):

*This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.*

Comment: I was attempting to accomplish this using `subset()` but I was unsure how I should use this newly generated subset to remove the values from the original dataframe.

Comment: If that are the values you want to exclude, then you just do the opposite: `filteredDF <- subset(dataframe, (x <= 1024 & y <= 768))` The logic is the same as in the logical vector proposed by Roland. If you just want to keep some columns after filtering, you may add the argument `select`.